# Intercept URL not working with grails

Tags: grails, spring-security, intercept

I am trying to secure some pages using intercept URL in grails. The configuration looks like this

```
 grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = SecurityConfigType.InterceptUrlMap
 grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/dashBoard/superAdmin':['ROLE_SUPERADMIN'],
    '/dashBoard/config':['ROLE_PRODMANADMIN'],
    '/dashBoard/reports':['ROLE_PRODMANADMIN'],
    '/game/*/**':['ROLE_SUPERADMIN'],
    '/bet/*/**':['ROLE_SUPERADMIN'],
    '/payment/*/**':['ROLE_SUPERADMIN'],
    '/*/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'],
    '/*':['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'],
    '/js/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/css/**':['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/images/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    '/favicon.ico': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
    ]
```

But when I try to login via the ROLE_SUPERADMIN, I get redirected to denied page. When I tried to print the authority of currently logged in user, it prints ROLE_SUPERADMIN. If I change the ROLE_SUPERADMIN to ROLE_ADMIN, it works, but I have to use the ROLE_SUPERADMIN in this case. So what am I doing wrong ? I am using spring security core

Answer (score 0):

Assign several roles to the user or map several roles to particular URL.

Answer (score 0):

All of the urls must be in lowercase (i.e. 'dashBoard' -> 'dashboard') - you should have been getting a warning at startup about this.